# Не видит контроллер ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, сервер

Пишу xamarin приложение. Пытаюсь обработать http запрос с помощью MVC контроллера. При попытке обратиться к контроллеру выводит 404 ошибку.  Сервер видит, тк  можно обратиться к базовой хтмл странице

```
[HttpPost]
public string Hello(string s)
{
    return ("Hello" + s);
}
```

код сервера

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private static readonly string HelloUrl="http://192.168.0.15/ServerDiaLog/My/Hello";
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"s", "Vasya"}
};
FormUrlEncodedContent form = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(HelloUrl,form);

string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
await DisplayAlert("У вас диабет", result, "ОК!");
```

(Название контроллера MyController)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

192.168.0.15 - статический локальный ip, который я себе выдал
My - Название контроллера
Hello - название метода
[image: RouteConfig.cs]
[image: MyController]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

отправка POST запроса из браузера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете править ваш вопрос, добавляйте всё детали туда

Comment: Так может не `http://192.168.0.15/ServerDiaLog/My/Hello`, а `http://192.168.0.15/My/Hello`?

Comment: "можно обратиться к базовой хтмл странице" - как?

Comment: В общем, "не воспроизводится". Показывайте свой роутинг и ваш контроллер, а не только экшн.

Comment: @AK `Сервер видит, тк можно обратиться к базовой хтмл странице` сервер видит походу что то другое, а не конкретно этот запрос

Comment: Поправил вопрос. http://192.168.0.15/My/Hello тоже не работает

Comment: Можно обратиться через браузер 192.168.0.15/ServerDiaLog/ (неявно запускается index.html)

Comment: Ну, это не вариант. У браузера могут быть такие настройки прокси и такие манипуляции с галкой "обходить локальные адреса", что мама не горюй. Но попробуйте прямо из браузера отправить POST-запрос (инструменты разработчика встроены во все браузеры, перейдите на закладку сеть, измените запрос на POST и ваш URL и переотправьте). Прикрепил в ответ скриншот для Firefox - кнопка F12

Comment: При отправке запросов начало выкидывать ошибку 500

Comment: @TMNT Прикладывайте свой веб-конфиг, правда я не уверен, что смогу понять в чём причина, т.к. именно классический asp.net mvc уже давно не ковыряю глубоко. Могу из общих соображений посоветовать следующее: написать, что за версия IIS стоит на 192.168.0.15, приложить свой конфиг и посмотреть в гите, что когда меняли, а главное - создать новое веб-приложение с дефолтным веб-конфигом и попробовать локально из visual студии, чтобы понимать - проблема вообще в конфиге или проблема в настройках IIS на конкретном сервере. Проблема в любом случае относится к инфраструктуре, её вопроизводить сложно.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Не, браузерные скриншоты уже неинтересны. Проблема как я уже сказал либо в веб-конфиге приложения, либо в настройках IIS. Пока ваш вопрос уже так распух в диагностике, что читать постороннему читателю вряд ли будет удобно. Я бы на вашем месте грохнул вопрос (он плохого качества по меркам SO: вы за все эти итерации правки так и не сформулировали ещё вопроизводимый вопрос), я бы уже давно начал другой, дав ссылку на этот и кратко просуммировав что вы знаете. Правда, прямо говоря, и новый вы вряд ли сформулируете нормально.

Comment: Давайте жёстко ребром разделим: либо проблема в конфиге, либо в настройках IIS и когда станет понятно, где - тогда и пойдёте создавать новый вопрос.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276878/iis-express-500-19-cannot-read-configuration-file-because-its-looking-at-th

Comment: У вас какой-то фичи IIS не хватает, попробуйте до-установить фичи, связанные с сервером приложений.

Answer (score 1):

И тем не менее код валидный, ищите ошибку в другом месте.

Вот тот же самый контроллер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тот же самый код в linqpad'е:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у вас стандартный роутинг — то проблема в том, что вы указываете путь не как /Controller/Action (В общем судя по всему у вас должно быть так: `http://192.168.0.15/ServerDiaLog/Hello`, откуда вы взяли `My`?)

Если роутинг нестандартный — то показывайте свои маршруты.

PS Попробуйте из браузера отправить запрос, например вот как это выглядит в Firefox:

Жмём F12:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По GET не находит, по POST отдаёт ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.+

Comment: @TMNT У вас всё равно неполный вопрос: вы не показали свои маршруты, но давайте попробуем представить, что вы там ничего не меняли. Тогда, с учётом `192.168.0.15 - статический локальный ip, который я себе выдал My - Название контроллера Hello - название метода` адрес должен быть `http://192.168.0.15/My/Hello`. Но если не заработает - будете по-честному показывать роуты (RouteConfig.cs) и атрибуты на контроллере.

Comment: К сожалению, даже так не работает. http://192.168.0.15/My/Hello. Дополнил вопрос

Comment: @TMNT Посмотрел дополнения, всё выглядит нормально и должно работать именно так как я и сказал -  `192.168.0.15/My/Hello`. Более того, я не поленился и собрал вот прям точно такой же проект, как у вас (до этого был .core и другие имена контроллеров и маршрутов). При запуске на локалхосте всё отрабатывает абсолютно так, как и задумывалось. Проблема не в этом. Проверяйте к какому адресу вы ходите, может это вообще не тот сервер. Попробуйте на локалхосте запустить оба фрагмента, чтобы увидеть, что у вас работает и проблемы не с кодом а с инфраструктурой.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.